# Why the PHP software is not getting updated to the latest stable released version?

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade, sudo, php

I'm using LAMP on my local machine which runs Ubuntu 12.04.

Currently I'm using PHP 5.5.20 on my machine.

Following is the command I run from the terminal and below that is the output:

```
~$ php -v
PHP 5.5.20-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Dec 21 2014 19:54:33) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

As there is a new version of PHP available, now I want to upgrade to it. In short I want to upgrade it to PHP 5.5.21.

So I tried following command:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It ran for some time, some output was getting generated, some operations were carrying on, the counter starts from 1% and goes through 100% and lot of things happen, but the PHP software version didn't get upgraded. So how should I get the upgraded version of PHP software?

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: How did you have installed. Have you added [this](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5) ppa.

Comment: @g_p: Do I need to add this ppa every time I want to upgrade PHP?

Comment: Yes you need this ppa if you want to fetch update from this ppa.  But this ppa also do not have PHP 5.5.21.

Comment: The latest version of php5 for Ubuntu 12.04 in ppa:ondrej/php5 is 5.5.20. This PPA gets updated frequently and fairly quickly, and you should be able to install php5 5.5.21 when it lands in ppa:ondrej/php5.

Comment: @g_p:You mean to say whenever I'll go for PHP software update it is mandatory for me to first add this ppa then run the command for upgrade. If I don't add the ppa and straight away go for upgrading the PHP software it won't get update. Am I getting you right?

Comment: Whenever you upgrade your system, it fetch package from the repo which has more recent version of package. If a ppa has more recent version of a package then the official Ubuntu repository, it will be fetched from the ppa.

Comment: Oh my...  the deb.sury.org is a volunteer project I run in the bits of my free time.  If you need a faster updates you will have to pay somebody do it, or you will have to just deal with it and wait.  That said - I am preparing the updates right now as of this moment (and Debian wheezy and jessie comes first in the queue)...

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of PHP in Ubuntu 12.04 is currently 5.3.10-1.

Given that you have 5.5.20-1, you clearly are using a third party PHP package, rather than the Ubuntu one.

With Ubuntu you can choose either to run the version supplied with Ubuntu, or run a third party package.  You seem to be doing the latter.

Probably the best choice of PPA for PHP is [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5) as it is maintained by the same team that maintains PHP packages in Debian.

If you're using a third party PHP package, then for any queries regarding when updates will be available, you should see that package maintainer.

Comment: Thank you so much neon_overload. Yes, you got it right. But could you please provide me the commands to upgrade PHP from the PPA you mentioned. Also let me know do I need to add this PPA every time I go for PHP software upgrade? Thanks once again.

Comment: If you still subscribe to the PPA (it's in your sources) then it will upgrade PHP automatically when you `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`, like with any other package.  Are you sure that the PPA has actually released an update?  Check on its project page.

Comment: I checked myself and their latest php5 for precise is 5.5.20+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1.  Which looks like what you've got.  Remember that just because upstream makes a release doesn't mean packagers will have it yet, even those with a rolling release will have a delay.